# Using one Save File Dialog Box in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, savefiledialog

Currently I have three separate save commands in my program: Write to Plain Text, Write to HTML, and Write to Excel File.

Each one is invoked by a different command on a menu. I would like to combine these three into one Save File Dialog on the program. I know that I would have to edit the "Filter" property of the dialog box to add in the other two types.

My questions, how do I code the program to save the file based off what is chosen from the filter. That's to say :

```
If "Selected = Microsoft Excel" Then
    * Save As Excel File
ElseIf "Selected = HTML Then
    * Save As HTML File
Else 
    * Save As Plain Text File
End If
```

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet to give you an idea. Sorry it's in C#, but it should be easy to convert to VB.

EDIT: here's the new code:

```
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text|*.txt|Word|*.docx";
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();            
if (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex == 2) MessageBox.Show("It's a Word doc.");
saveFileDialog1.Dispose();
```

Comment: Is there a way to define a default extension when using this method? Like if Text is selected to auto append .txt to the end of it.

Comment: @PaulWilliams It's automatic. To see that, you can (temporarily) set the `Text` property of your form to the file's name. In C# it would be done like this: `Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;` . What I get if I type "abc" is: `C:\Users\...\abc.txt`.